# How to write Inner class in WinRT C++

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I am trying to port C++/C Library in Win Rt. The Old Library contains lot of inner classes.

I wondering how to convert those classes in Win Rt. I goggled it didn't find any example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular classes you can do it the same way as before.
In ref classes you can declare internal/private classes only.

```
public ref class Class1 sealed
{
public:
    Class1();

internal:

    class Class2
    {
    public:
        void Do();
    };
};
```